# restangular: addRequestInterceptor: generate an error if response is malformed

Tags: restangular

In my addRequestInterceptor function I want to make sure I get proper response structure and generate an error if not.
For instance, I expect the server response to getList to be response.data.items eg `{ data: items: [...] }` (as per [google style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jsoncstyleguide.xml#JSON_Structure_&_Reserved_Property_Names))
So I would want the request interceptor function to generate an error if the structure is not valid (as opposed to returning undefined, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Restangular docs for configuration.

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addresponseinterceptor

```
app.config(function(RestangularProvider) {

    // add a response intereceptor
    RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {

      //Done if the getList operation type is made so that you don't do the same for a single get
      if(operation === 'getList'){

        //Checks if items is undefined and if it is an array
        if(!angular.isUndefined(data.items) && angular.isArray(data.items)){
           deferred.resolve(data.items);
        } else {
           deferred.reject({error: 'Malformed Response. That is not right!'});
        }

      } else {
           //Just continue and resolve the data on other operations
           //Add whatever else you want for handling responses
           deferred.resolve(data);
      }

    });
```

You can then handle the error on the error function of the request in your .then() on the request resource.

Comment: Outside of that, i'm still exploring other options on throwing errors.

Comment: I think errorInterceptor isn't relevant because it will never reach it - the response is a 200 with response data, but the content is malformed.
I do use addResponseInterceptor to extract data.data.items and return that, but couldn't figure out a way to generate an error if response data is not in that structure...
Re rejecting deferred - I do not understand in what context that exists in you example.

Comment: I changed it to be a little more clear. Pretty much, you have to check the response data to be the way you want. You can also utilize the what and/or operation type to get a more clear idea of what kind of request it is.